# gem install jekyll error on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I have created new twitter-bootstrap project on Webstorm 7 and updated npm then executed the grunt comment I got the below error in Jekyll

```
Running "jekyll:docs" (jekyll) task Warning: 
Please install Jekyll before running this task. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Then I followed the steps as given by (http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2011/09/01/runningjekyllwindows.html) URL now I am getting error on

```
gem install jekyll
```

step. Please look at the below error log on gem_make.out file

> C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" generating stemmer-i386-mingw32.def compiling porter.c
>   make: execvp: gcc: Bad file number make: *** [porter.o] Error 127

Please guide me how to come over this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide on [How to Run Jekyll on Windows](https://github.com/juthilo/run-jekyll-on-windows).

It covers installing the Ruby DevKit, which is most likely what you're missing.

Alternately, and assuming you're on Windows, you could install Ruby using [scoop](http://scoop.sh), it's very simple to use and it will install the DevKit along with Ruby.

I hope this helps.